# unsigned long long to binary

Tags: binary, unsigned-long-long-int

I am trying to check the set bits of an unsigned long long in c++ using below algorithm which only checks whether the bit is set or not.But my problem is the answer that I get is wrong.Please help me understand how unsigned long long is stored in binary.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1<<(pos)))
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int pos=sizeof(unsigned long long)*8;
    unsigned long long a;
    cin>>a;
    pos=pos-1;
    while(pos>=0)
    {
        if(CHECK_BIT(a,pos))
          cout<<"1";
        else
          cout<<"0";
        --pos;
    }
}
```

Input :

```
1000000000000000000
```

Output:

```
1010011101100100000000000000000010100111011001000000000000000000
```

Expected Output:

```
110111100000101101101011001110100111011001000000000000000000
```

Similarly for another input:

```
14141
```

Output :

```
0000000000000000001101110011110100000000000000000011011100111101
```

Expected Output:

```
11011100111101
```

In the second example(in fact for any small number) the binary pattern just repeats itself after 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have is an issue in the bit set macro , please replace it w/

```
#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1LL<<(pos)))
```

Comment: @g4ur4v No problem. BTW please avoid (unsigned long long)*8 , instead of multiply by 8 (kindof magic number) use CHAR_BIT (its more readable) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200954/what-is-char-bit