# How to set bit in C

Tags: c, bit

There's a variable:

```
char segment = 0;
```

After 1 or with bit 15, segment = 1;

Just means this bit check already.

Question is how to cancel the mark of bit 15 (set back to 0)?

Use "~"?

Comment: `char` only has 8 bits (not 15)

Comment: @mvp is correct - also, see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/2065121

Comment: sorry, I just started learning C language.
0 0 0 1 set back  to 0 0 0 0

Comment: `char` does **NOT**  only have 8 bits, this is a property of the implementation which you can find out by using `CHAR_BIT` from `limits.h`. Please don't perpetuate inaccuracies.

Comment: correction, @paxdiablo is correct, one old dog, one new trick http://stackoverflow.com/a/3200969/2065121

Comment: Eitherway, from the subsequent comment it seems that @Yun actually means the *least significant bit*, normally designated bit zero.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the MSB of an 8-bit character for example, you can AND with 0x7F

e.g. segment = segment & 0x7F;

To dynamically produce the mask, you can use bit shifting operations (i.e. the << operator).

Answer (score 1):

Following program sets bit, clears bit and toggles bit

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
unsigned int byte;
unsigned int bit_position;
unsigned int tempbyte = 0x01;
//get the values of the byte and the bit positions 
//set bit
byte = (byte | (tempbyte << bit_position));// set the bit at the position given by bit_position
//clear bit
byte = (byte & ~(tempbyte << bit_position));//clear the bit at the position given by bit_position
//toggle bits
byte = (byte ^ (tempbyte << bit_position));//toggle the bit at the position given by bit_position
}
```