# How to copy arrray to array using memcpy() in C

Tags: c

I am trying copy an array `(temp)` from another array `a`.
But I have it is not happening.

`Fig-1`

```
int main()
{
    typedef int arr_1[3];
    arr_1 arr[4];
    arr_1 *temp;
    arr_1 a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(temp, a, sizeof(temp));
}
```

But when I tried with a simple program like below,

`Fig-2`

```
 main()
    {
    int abc[3], def[3];
    def[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    memcpy(abc, def, sizeof(abc));
    }
```

This above code `(fig-2)` worked really fine for me.
But `fig-1` is not working for me. Both are alomost same.
But why the `fig-1` is not working??

Comment: `sizeof(temp)` is the size of a pointer (to an `int[3]`).

Comment: @All: Johnny Mnemonic tips worked for me. I just replaced memset with `temp = (arr_1*)malloc(sizeof(arr_1));`. And it worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must allocate memory for `temp` with `malloc()` for example. For now it`s just an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 9):

Because `temp` is not an array, it's a pointer and therefore `sizeof(temp)` has absolutely no relation to the array.

You want to change the `memcpy` to use `sizeof(a)`. You will also want to give `temp` a sane value before copying to it, otherwise the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlokSave: Johnny Mnemonic tips worked for me. I just replaced memset with `temp = (arr_1*)malloc(sizeof(arr_1));`. And it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I know, I'm late. But when I read the previous answers I though "you do not need all these variables"

with your simple sample :

```
int abc[3], def[3]; //abs is destination and def is source
def[3] = {1, 2, 3};
memcpy(abc, def, 3*sizeof(int)); //you can do sizeof(int) as you have here an array of int.
```

But it is better to use a variable "const int array_size = 3" or "#define ARRAY_SIZE 3" to define your array size. Then you just have to replace the "3" by "ARRAY_SIZE" and it does the same job and avoid size mistakes.

With your real problem you can do :

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 3

typedef int arr_1[ARRAY_SIZE];
arr_1 arr[ARRAY_SIZE+1];//it is useless here
arr_1 *temp = (arr_1 *) malloc(sizeof(arr_1)); //it is your destination, but you have a pointer of array
arr_1 a[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3};//it is your source

//by doing sizeof((*temp)[0])
//you do not care about the type of you array pointer
//you are sure to take the good size --> it fills your array with 0
memset((*temp), 0, (ARRAY_SIZE+1)*sizeof((*temp)[0])); 

//same logic
//but you destination is (*temp) because you have a pointer of array
//it means that your array arr and a have the same type
memcpy((*temp), a, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(a[0]));  

//by the way, the las cell of arr is still 0
//and a pointer is close to an array. If you do "tmp = a;" it works.
//but it is not a copy, you just give the a's reference to tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

as summary of the previous answers:

you should allocate memory for `tmp` with size = `sizeof(a)`. And then `memcpy` with size =  `sizeof(a)`

```
arr_1 a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
arr_1 *temp = malloc(sizeof(a));
memcpy(temp, a, sizeof(a));
```

and do not forget to free `temp` when it became useless in your program with `free(temp);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider an helper function.
See [commit 45ccef8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45ccef87b3cc0ab09ec5fd1186aa0b33298ee8d4), [commit 60566cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60566cbb5890abc84fa18c56da70e35ace0b23bf) (25 Sep 2016) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b1f0a85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1f0a856605981363053941b8210f3cc9389607a), 03 Oct 2016)</sup>

It uses [`COPY_ARRAY`, a safe and convenient helper](https://github.com/git/git/blob/60566cbb5890abc84fa18c56da70e35ace0b23bf/git-compat-util.h#L788-L794) for copying arrays,
complementing [`ALLOC_ARRAY`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/60566cbb5890abc84fa18c56da70e35ace0b23bf/git-compat-util.h#L785) and [`REALLOC_ARRAY`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/60566cbb5890abc84fa18c56da70e35ace0b23bf/git-compat-util.h#L786).

So instead of `memcpy(temp, a, sizeof(a));`, you would use `COPY_ARRAY(temp, a, 1);`

> Users just specify source, destination and the number of elements; the size of an element is inferred automatically.
>
> It checks if the multiplication of size and element count overflows.
>   The inferred size is passed first to `st_mult`, which allows the division
>   there to be done at compilation time.
>
> As a basic type safety check it makes sure the sizes of source and
>   destination elements are the same.  That's evaluated at compilation time
>   as well.
>
> `COPY_ARRAY` is safe to use with `NULL` as source pointer iff 0 elements are
>   to be copied.
>   That convention is used in some cases for initializing arrays.
>   [Raw `memcpy(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) does not support it -- compilers are allowed to
>   assume that only valid pointers are passed to it and can optimize away
>   `NULL` checks after such a call.

```
#define COPY_ARRAY(dst, src, n) copy_array((dst), (src), (n), sizeof(*(dst)) + \
    BUILD_ASSERT_OR_ZERO(sizeof(*(dst)) == sizeof(*(src))))
static inline void copy_array(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n, size_t size)
{
    if (n)
        memcpy(dst, src, st_mult(size, n));
}
```

---

It uses the [macro `BUILD_ASSERT_OR_ZERO`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89c855ed3cbe64bea93ea081d0e96077e9ee8517/git-compat-util.h#L46-L59) which asserts a build-time dependency, as an expression (with `@cond` being the compile-time condition which must be true).
The compilation will fail if the condition isn't true, or can't be evaluated by the compiler.

```
#define BUILD_ASSERT_OR_ZERO(cond) \
(sizeof(char [1 - 2*!(cond)]) - 1)
```

Example:

```
#define foo_to_char(foo)                \
     ((char *)(foo)                     \
      + BUILD_ASSERT_OR_ZERO(offsetof(struct foo, string) == 0))
```

---

[The inline function `st_mult`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/320d0b493a259db3b481f985545b244438e6c086/git-compat-util.h#L734-L740) is introduced in [commit 320d0b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/320d0b493a259db3b481f985545b244438e6c086)

```
static inline size_t st_mult(size_t a, size_t b)
{
    if (unsigned_mult_overflows(a, b))
        die("size_t overflow: %"PRIuMAX" * %"PRIuMAX,
            (uintmax_t)a, (uintmax_t)b);
    return a * b;
}
```

`st_mult` is part helper functions for detecting `size_t` overflow, which include [`unsigned_mult_overflows`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/320d0b493a259db3b481f985545b244438e6c086/git-compat-util.h#L99-L105)

> Performing computations on `size_t` variables that we feed to `xmalloc` and friends can be dangerous, as an integer overflow can cause us to allocate a much smaller chunk than we realized.
>
> We already have [`unsigned_add_overflows()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/320d0b493a259db3b481f985545b244438e6c086/git-compat-util.h#L96-L97), but let's add
>   `unsigned_mult_overflows()` to that

```
/*
 * Returns true if the multiplication of "a" and "b" will
 * overflow. The types of "a" and "b" must match and must be unsigned.
 * Note that this macro evaluates "a" twice!
 */
#define unsigned_mult_overflows(a, b) \
((a) && (b) > maximum_unsigned_value_of_type(a) / (a))
```

---

That uses [`maximum_unsigned_value_of_type`: helper for detecting unsigned overflow](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1368f65002bf39fdde7dd736a75ae35475184371/git-compat-util.h#L34-L35)  (from [commit 1368f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1368f65002bf39fdde7dd736a75ae35475184371))

> The idiom `(a + b < a)` works fine for detecting that an unsigned integer has overflowed, but a more explicit

```
unsigned_add_overflows(a, b)
```

> might be easier to read.
>
> Define such a macro, expanding roughly to `((a) < UINT_MAX - (b))`.
>   Because the expansion uses each argument only once outside of `sizeof()`
>   expressions, it is safe to use with arguments that have side effects.

```
#define bitsizeof(x) (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x))

#define maximum_unsigned_value_of_type(a) \
(UINTMAX_MAX >> (bitsizeof(uintmax_t) - bitsizeof(a)))
```

with [`CHAR_BIT` being the number of bits in char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200969/6309) (architecture-dependent)

---

You can see an example with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)

See [commit 921d49b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/921d49be86bd44ca290c8db6cc6f419dac3ed442), [commit 177fbab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/177fbab747da4f58cb2a8ce010b3515c86dd67c9) (15 Jun 2019) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e8d2590](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8d259064146f24abb1280aff0ca3ead20218244), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### use `COPY_ARRAY` for copying arrays
>
> Convert calls of `memcpy(3)` to use `COPY_ARRAY`, which shortens and
>   simplifies the code a bit.