# Convert from base 10 to base 2 using bitwise operations

Tags: c

As in title i'm trying to convert decimal number to binary.
I set the lowest int as i coudl

```
char * toBinary(int num)
{

    int i = 1 << 31;
    while(i!=0)
    {
        if((num & i) == 0 )
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
        i >>= 1;
        printf("%d", i);
        getchar();
    }
}
```

but it does not work, after every shift `i` is still negative number, what shoudl i change ?

Comment: Where is the decimal number???

Comment: I found same program explained here on YouTube - https://youtu.be/1MJ1o56x-g8  hope this will help you more than anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several errors both with your code and with your description of what it does.  Here is a corrected version:

```
void print_binary(unsigned x)
{
    for (unsigned bit = 1u << 31; bit != 0; bit >>= 1)
        putchar((x & bit) ? '1' : '0');
}
```

Errors:

- The function should not return `char *`, since it doesn't return anything.  If you want to make a function that returns a string, that is different.
- You cannot compute `1 << 31`, because that is an overflow.  You must use unsigned numbers: `1u << 31` is okay (assuming `int` is 32 bits).
- You are not converting from decimal to binary.  The input number is already in binary, you are simply printing it out in binary.

Comment: i thought only difference between int and unsigned int is that last bit is sign bit, why i cant shift signed int like i did ?

Comment: The problem is that when you shift a signed number to the right it "sign fills".  An unsigned number is zero-filled.

Comment: @whd Before coming to SO I was also unaware of this, similarly one more  interesting thing is `~0` is undefined (or may be implementation) where as `~0u` is well defined!!

Answer (score 3):

Use unsigned `i`.

```
int i = 1 << 31;
```

correct as:

```
unsigned int i = 1u << 31;
```

Additionally, instead of using `31` I would like to suggest you to write size independent code (size of int can be different in different machine).

Do like:

```
unsigned int mask = 1u << ((sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
```

I have named `mask` instead `i`, write like this code.

```
//conversion 
unsigned int mask = 1u << ((sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);   
while(mask > 0){
  if((num & mask) == 0 )
       printf("0");
  else
       printf("1")
   mask = mask >> 1 ;  // Right Shift 
}
```

From @[Carl Norum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116908/carl-norum)'s comment: To correctly write a size platform independent code use  `CHAR_BIT` macro defined in `limits.h` header file. Note `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in `char` and it is  possible that in some implementation of C a byte may *not* be equals to 8 bits.

Read: [What is `CHAR_BIT`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200954/what-is-char-bit)

Comment: `1 << 31` is undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Because of bit overflow ?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Corrected now.

Comment: If you want platform independent code you need to use `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`, too.

Comment: @CarlNorum I know in some implementation a byte may not be equals to 8 bit but I don't know  `CHAR_BIT`. Which header file I need to include?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - it's in `limits.h`.

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks Carl I should improve my answer. I was unaware of this Thanks.

Comment: Is i>>1 when i=1 undefined behaviour, too?, or just zero? What if i=0?

Comment: @zubergu No, also note `1 << 31` is undefined because `1` was singed but I corrected this as `1u << 31` from Dietrich Epp's answer. for unsigned number it is not undefined behavior.

Comment: So right-shift guarantees that variable will be zero at some point(when variable is unsigned)? And going one step further also is guaranteed to result in 0, correct?

Comment: @zubergu Yes `<<` is implementation dependent/undefined because of trap set.

Comment: @zubergu I read sometime from [here](https://is.muni.cz/www/408176/38744863/International_Standard_for_C.txt) last time when I was answering.