# Where is nat base 10 converted to num base 2?

Tags: isabelle

For `term "15::nat"`, the value 15 is automatically converted to the binary value `(num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 num.One)))`. I would like to know where that's done, so I can know how it's done.

(**Small update**: I know that 15 is a type class `numeral` constant, which gets converted to binary `Num.num`, which gets mapped to `nat`, so maybe the `nat` is decimal, or maybe it's binary. However, my basic question remains the same. Where is the decimal to binary conversion done?)

I show below how I know about the conversion.

I define notation to show me that [Num.numeral :: (num => 'a)](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/HOL/Num.thy#l243) is coercing 15 to `Num.num`.

```
abbreviation nat_of_numeral :: "num => nat" where
  "nat_of_numeral n == (numeral n)"

notation nat_of_numeral ("n@N|_" [1000] 1000)
```

Next, 15 gets coerced to binary in a `term` command:

```
term "15::nat"
(*The output:*)
term "n@N|(num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 num.One))) :: nat"
```

And next, 15 gets coerced before it gets used in a proof goal:

```
lemma "15 = n@N|(num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 num.One)))" (*
  goal (1 subgoal):
   1. n@N|(num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 num.One))) =
      n@N|(num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 num.One))) *)
by(rule refl)
```

The conversion seems to be decently fast, as shown by this:

```
(*140 digits: 40ms*)
term "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
  ::nat"
```

I also want to convert base 2 to base 10, but if I see how the above is done, it might show me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the overview of how I think it's done.

It starts in the [Num.thy `parse_translation`](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/HOL/Num.thy#l293), at the ML function [`numeral_tr`](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/HOL/Num.thy#l306).

In that function, there is the use of [`Lexicon.read_xnum` of lexicon.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/Pure/Syntax/lexicon.ML#l389), which takes a string argument.

I don't know the details, but string `"15"` is extracted from an expression like

```
  "15 = n@N|(num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 num.One)))",
```

and fed to `read_xnum`, where there is this equivalency:

```
  Lexicon.read_xnum "15" = {leading_zeros = 0, radix = 10, value = 15}
```

In `read_xnum` the function [`Library.read_radix_int` of library.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/Pure/library.ML#l670) is used, and it takes as arguments an integer radix and a list of digits, such as shown in this equivalency:

```
  Library.read_radix_int 10 ["1","5"] = (15, []);
```

Next, the conversion from `15` to `(num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 (num.Bit1 num.One)))` is a result of [`IntInf.quotRem` in the `parse_translation`](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/HOL/Num.thy#l297).

This takes me out of convenient HTML linking for [isabelle.in.tum.de/repos](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba).

`IntInf.quotRem` is in Isabelle2013-2\contrib\polyml-5.5.1-1\src\basis\IntInf.sml, and is defined as

```
  val quotRem: int*int->int*int = RunCall.run_call2C2 POLY_SYS_quotrem,
```

which leads to Isabelle2013-2\contrib\polyml-5.5.1-1\src\basis\RuntimeCalls.ML line 83:

```
  val POLY_SYS_quotrem = 104 (* DCJM 05/03/10 *).
```

For Windows that takes me to Isabelle2013-2\contrib\polyml-5.5.1-1\src\libpolyml\x86asm.asm line 1660, though I could be leaving out some important details:

```
  quotrem_really_long:
    MOVL    Reax,Redi
  CALLMACRO   CALL_IO    POLY_SYS_quotrem
  CALLMACRO   RegMask quotrem,(M_Reax OR M_Redi OR M_Redx OR Mask_all).
```

I think that's enough of an overview to answer my question. A string "15" is converted to an ML integer, and then some assembly language level quotient/remainder division is used to convert 15 to binary `Num.num`.

I'm actually only interested in how "15" is converted to 15 in `read_radix_int`, and whether the details of that function will help me. I explain the application more below.

From here, I put in more detail for myself, to put in a nice form much of the information I collected.

## What's sort of the deal

I start with a binary number as a `bool list`, something like `[True, True, True, True]` for binary 15, though here, I simplify it in some ways.

That then gets converted to something like `[[True, False, True, False], [True, False, True]]`, which is decimal 15.

## The real problem can be finding the right search phrase

Searching on something like ["decimal to binary conversion"](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=decimal+to+binary+conversion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=BW6WU_ufDMWS8QfWpYHQBg) returns links to a lot of basic math algorithms, which aren't what I'm looking for.

Normal programming conversions aren't what I need either, which is just making explicit the underlying fact that integers are already in binary form:

- [Convert from base 10 to base 2 using bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254118/convert-from-base-10-to-base-2-using-bitwise-operations)
- [C: Convert decimal to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280336/c-convert-decimal-to-binary)

Finally, other searches led me to the right word, "radix". Additionally, I resorted to doing searches on how things are done in C, where bit shifts are what I'm trying to tie into, though these may not be what I need:

- [Binary to decimal and decimal to binary base conversion using bitwise operators in C](http://whirlcode.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/binary-to-decimal-and-decimal-to-binary.html)
- [C Program to Convert Decimal to Binary using Bitwise AND operator](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/decimal-to-binary-using-bitwise-and.html)

## Radix leading back to Num.thy

"Radix" took me back to Num.thy, which is where I thought the action might be, but hadn't seen anything that was obvious to me.

I include some source from Num.thy, lexicon.ML, and IntInf.sml:

```
(* THE TWO MAIN EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS IN THE TRANSLATIONS: read_xnum, quotRem *)
ML{* 
  Lexicon.read_xnum;       (* string -> 
                               {leading_zeros: int, radix: int, value: int}.*)
  Lexicon.read_xnum "15";  (* {leading_zeros = 0, radix = 10, value = 15}.*)
  Lexicon.read_xnum "15" = {leading_zeros = 0, radix = 10, value = 15};

  IntInf.quotRem;          (* int * int -> int * int.*)
  IntInf.quotRem (5,3);    (* (1, 2) *)
*}

parse_translation {* (* Num.thy(293) *)
  let
    fun num_of_int n =
      if n > 0 then
        (case IntInf.quotRem (n, 2) of
          (0, 1) => Syntax.const @{const_name One}
        | (n, 0) => Syntax.const @{const_name Bit0} $ num_of_int n
        | (n, 1) => Syntax.const @{const_name Bit1} $ num_of_int n)
      else raise Match
    val pos = Syntax.const @{const_name numeral}
    val neg = Syntax.const @{const_name neg_numeral}
    val one = Syntax.const @{const_name Groups.one}
    val zero = Syntax.const @{const_name Groups.zero}
    fun numeral_tr [(c as Const (@{syntax_const "_constrain"}, _)) $ t $ u] =
          c $ numeral_tr [t] $ u
      | numeral_tr [Const (num, _)] =
          let
            val {value, ...} = Lexicon.read_xnum num;
          in
            if value = 0 then zero else
            if value > 0
            then pos $ num_of_int value
            else neg $ num_of_int (~value)
          end
      | numeral_tr ts = raise TERM ("numeral_tr", ts);
  in [("_Numeral", K numeral_tr)] end
*}

ML{* (* lexicon.ML(367) *)    
  (* read_xnum: hex/bin/decimal *)      
  local     
  val ten = ord "0" + 10;
  val a = ord "a";
  val A = ord "A";
  val _ = a > A orelse raise Fail "Bad ASCII";

  fun remap_hex c =
    let val x = ord c in
      if x >= a then chr (x - a + ten)
      else if x >= A then chr (x - A + ten)
      else c
    end;      
  fun leading_zeros ["0"] = 0
    | leading_zeros ("0" :: cs) = 1 + leading_zeros cs
    | leading_zeros _ = 0;      
  in      
  fun read_xnum str =
    let
      val (sign, radix, digs) =
        (case Symbol.explode (perhaps (try (unprefix "#")) str) of
          "0" :: "x" :: cs => (1, 16, map remap_hex cs)
        | "0" :: "b" :: cs => (1, 2, cs)
        | "-" :: cs => (~1, 10, cs)
        | cs => (1, 10, cs));
    in
     {radix = radix,
      leading_zeros = leading_zeros digs,
      value = sign * #1 (Library.read_radix_int radix digs)}
    end;      
  end;  
*}

ML{* (* IntInf.sml(42) *)
  val quotRem: int*int->int*int = RunCall.run_call2C2 POLY_SYS_quotrem
*}
```

## A big part of what I was looking for; radix again

```
(* THE FUNCTION WHICH TRANSLATES A LIST OF DIGITS/STRINGS TO A ML INTEGER *)
ML{* 
  Library.read_radix_int;     (* int -> string list -> int * string list *)
  Library.read_radix_int 10 ["1","5"];  (* (15, []): int * string list.*)
  Library.read_radix_int 10 ["1","5"] = (15, []);
*}

ML{* (* library.ML(670)  *)
  fun read_radix_int radix cs =
    let
      val zero = ord "0";
      val limit = zero + radix;
      fun scan (num, []) = (num, [])
        | scan (num, c :: cs) =
            if zero <= ord c andalso ord c < limit then
              scan (radix * num + (ord c - zero), cs)
            else (num, c :: cs);
    in scan (0, cs) end;
*}
```

## The low-level division action

There's the high-level [`Integer.div_mod` in integer.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/Pure/General/integer.ML#l39), which wasn't used for the translation above:

```
  fun div_mod x y = IntInf.divMod (x, y);
```

In Isabelle2013-2\contrib\polyml-5.5.1-1\src\basis\IntInf.sml, the higher-level `divMod` can be compared to the lower-level `quotRem`:

```
  ML{* (* IntInf.sml(42) *)
    val quotRem: int*int->int*int = RunCall.run_call2C2 POLY_SYS_quotrem

    (* This should really be defined in terms of quotRem. *)
    fun divMod(i, j) = (i div j, i mod j)
  *}
```

With the low-level action for `quotRem` apparently being done at the assembly language level:

```
  ML{* (* RuntimeCalls.ML(83) *)
    val POLY_SYS_quotrem = 104 (* DCJM 05/03/10 *)
  *}

  (* x86asm.asm(1660)
    quotrem_really_long:
        MOVL    Reax,Redi
    CALLMACRO   CALL_IO    POLY_SYS_quotrem
    CALLMACRO   RegMask quotrem,(M_Reax OR M_Redi OR M_Redx OR Mask_all)
  *)
```

These various forms of `div` and `mod` are important to me.

I'm thinking that `div` and `mod` are to be avoided if possible, but tying into `quotRem` would be the way to go, I think, if division is unavoidable.