# sign function in C using bit operators only

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to implement a sign function using only bitwise operators.  I know that if I just want to extract the sign bit of a signed integer, I can do: `(x >> 31) & 1`.

Also, I understand that conditionals can be written as boolean expressions:

`if(x) a=y else a=z` which is equivalent to `a = x ? y:z` can be rewritten as:

`a=( (x<<31) << 31 ) & y + ( !x << 31) >> 31) & z`, assuming x=1 or 0.

This problem gets a little tricky though because I have 3 conditional scenarios:
return 1 if positive, 0 if zero, and -1 if negative.

I was thinking that in order to do this properly, I need to use `!` operator and the fact that `!0x<nonzero #>=0`, `!0x0=1`, `!0x1=0`.

So I came up with something like this, which is incorrect:

```
/*                                                                              
 * sign - return 1 if positive, 0 if zero, and -1 if negative                   
 *  Examples: sign(130) = 1                                                     
 *            sign(-23) = -1                                                    
 *  Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>                                                                          
 */
int sign(int x) {
    return (x>>31) & -1 ) + ( !( !x >> 31 ) & 1;
}
```

I think I have all the pieces but just not quite sure how to put them all together.  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just write the obvious code and let the compiler optimizer do the hard work for you?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm assuming this is a homework problem.

Comment: Using the compiler to get an answer to a homework problem is not necessarily wrong. :)

Comment: That's a rather daft thing to try. (x > 0 ? 1 : x < 0 ? -1 : 0) is a perfectly fine, portable and readable solution. Anything more complicated is nonsense.

Comment: @gnasher729 Those operators are not in the allowed list.

Comment: So what? This is a programming site, not a site for masochists.

Comment: Programmers follow problem constraints.

Comment: Do you know bit twiddles? https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html. My comment is just a contribution, not an answer.

Comment: OP: Using (x >> 31) & 1 to extract the sign bit is, depending on the C implementation and the number of value bits in an int, either implementation defined, or undefined behaviour, or wrong.

Comment: Any of these clever "bit hacks", especially those involving shifting to the right, are just waiting to be invalidated by an aggressive compiler optimizer. *Write the obvious code.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [bit hacks page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign) suggests this expression:

```
sign = (v != 0) | (v >> 31);
```

It can be rewritten without `!=` like this:

```
sign = (!!v) | (v >> 31);
```

([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/T6HCpE)).

I prefer this expression that does not use bit manipulation, though (from the same page).

```
sign = (v > 0) - (v < 0);
```

Comment: This returns 1 if v == 0.

Comment: The first two are badly non-portable, the last one is perfectly fine and correct. With the additional benefit that it works for all real types, including signed, unsigned, all sizes, and floating point.

Comment: @gnasher729 The first two can be made less non-portable with the expression from the linked page (i.e. `sizeof(int)*BITS_PER_BYTE-1`, where `BITS_PER_BYTE` defines the number of bits in a byte on a target computer). I do love the last one the most, that's why I mentioned it, even though I think it's against OP's rules.

Comment: `BITS_PER_BYTE`? Why not the standard `CHAR_BIT`?

Comment: @Deduplicator Because `BITS_PER_BYTE` is self-explanatory, while `CHAR_BITS` [requires a lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3200954/335858).

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight .  The second equation is what I was looking for.  Is there a way to systematically come up with these solutions? It's so convoluted to me.

Comment: `v >> 31` causes implementation-defined behaviour

Comment: @user1527227 Unfortunately, bit twiddling is more an art than a science. My strategy has been to bookmark the link from the first paragraph of the answer, and refer to it for all my bit manipulation needs.

Comment: @user1527227 It is convoluted, your question is "How do I do this simple task in a convoluted manner"

Comment: @dasblinkenlight fair enough.  Thank you.  Just thought I'd try ;).

Answer (score 0):

This one also works if the right shift is a binary one, rather than an arithmetic one:

```
unsigned int x;
static_assert (sizeof(x) == 4);

(~ (!!x)) + 1 + ( ( (x+0x7FFFFFFF) & 0x80000000 )  >> 30 )
```

or

```
(~ (!!x)) + 1 + ( ( !!( (x+0x7FFFFFFF) & 0x80000000 ) ) << 1 )
```

Explanation:

`(~ (!!x)) + 1` gives you 0 for x==0 and -1 otherwise.

`( ( (x+0x7FFFFFFF) & 0x80000000 )  >> 30 )` gives you 2 for x>0 and 0 otherwise.