# How to read a single bit from binary file in C++?

Tags: c++, input, binary

We're doing some experiment on random number.
The data given me is stored in a .bin file, and according to the provider, it's stored in independent bits, that is, every bit is the supposed bool random variable.

Now I would like to use this input in program, but as bool take 1 BYTE and int take 4 bytes, I don't know how to read it into a variable in C++. And it seems that the ifstream.read(s,n) also only takes n as number of char.

Is there any way to read bit data from file? Thank you!

Comment: You do realize that chars and ints and bytes consist of bits, right? You can't read one bit at a time, but you can read 8 bits at a time. Think of `ifstream.read(s,n)` as reading `8*n` bits, rather than `n` bytes.

Answer (score 8):

If every char is 8 bits, then you can discover the state of each bit like this:

```
// @param bit = 0 - 7
inline bool get_bit(char c, int bit)
{
    return (c >> n) & 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The smallest unit of information that can be read from a file is a `char` (8 bits<sup>1</sup>). To extract a particular bit from a `char`, you can do something like:

```
char c = 0xa5;
int n = 2;
int bit = (c >> n) & 1;
printf("bit = %d\n", bit);
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>If I don't include this, then somebody will point out that a `char` doesn't always have to be 8 bits, and it depends on [`CHAR_BIT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200954/what-is-char-bit) as defined by your compiler, but on all reasonable platforms today, a `char` is 8 bits.</sup>