# MSB (1-bit most left) index in C

Tags: c

How can I get the most significative 1-bit index from an unsigned integer (`uint16_t`)?

Example:

```
uint16_t x = // 0000 0000 1111 0000 = 240
printf("ffs=%d", __builtin_ffs(allowed)); // ffs=4
```

There is a function (`__builtin_ffs`) that return the least significative 1-bit (LSB) from a unsigned integer.

I want something *opposite*, I want some function which returns `8` applied to above example.

**Remark**: I have tried building my own function but I have found some problems with datatype size, which depends by compiler.

Comment: Bit numbers should always start at zero. There are very few places where they start at 1. So your example should return 7.

Comment: I agree with @JonathonReinhart, as it makes sense to have bit n represent 2^n. That said, I answered in accordance with your example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest/most efficient way to find the highest set bit (msb) in an integer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i)

Answer (score 1):

From the GCC manual at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html:

> - Built-in Function: int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)
>
> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

So, highest set bit:

```
#define ONE_BASED_INDEX_OF_HIGHEST_SET_BIT(x) \
    (CHAR_BIT * sizeof 1 - __builtin_clz(x)) // 1-based index!!
```

beware of `x == 0` or `x<0 && sizeof(x)<sizeof 0` though.

Comment: What does `CHAT_BIT` mean?

Comment: @Israel [`CHAR_BIT`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3200969/119527) is the number of bits in a `char` (byte) - nowdays, normally 8.

Comment: Since `__builtin_clz()` takes an unsigned int argument, I think it should be `CHAR_BIT * sizeof int - __builtin_clz(x)`, since `x` will be promoted to int.  Also note the lack of "-1" because the OP numbers bits starting from 1 and wants his example to return 8.

Answer (score 0):

if I am reading this right (am I? I'm a little rusty on this stuff) you can do this as follows:

```
int msb = 0;
while(x) { // while there are still bits
    x >>= 1; // right-shift the argument
    msb++; // each time we right shift the argument, increment msb
}
```

Comment: `x>>1;` has no effect. I edited your answer to do what you intended. However, I believe this still produces an answer that is off by one.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thank you for the correction. As for off by one, are you sure? 0 returns 0, 1 returns 1, 2 (0x10) or 3(0x11) return 2, etc...

Comment: `Test value: 0x0000F00D
    __builtin_clz: 16
    Deduplicator: 15
    RobP: 16`

Comment: comment on Deduplicator's answer: Also note the lack of "-1" because the OP numbers bits starting from 1 and wants his example to return 8.

Comment: Ah, I suppose you are technically correct. Removed my downvote, as this is much closer now.