# How to determine processor word length in C?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

I have met a question "How to determine processor word length without using sizeof() in C?" in an interview and I believed I gave the wrong answer.

My code was as follows:

```
int main(){
    int num = -1;
    int count = 0;    

    unsigned int num_copy = (unsigned int)num;
    while(num_copy >>= 1){
        count++;
    }

    printf("System size of int:%d", (count  + 1)/ 8);

    return 0;
}
```

The output answer is only decided by compiler options. So, how can I get the right answer (system word length)?

What if I change part of this question from 'processor word length' to 'operating system word length'?

Comment: What is wrong with `sizeof`?

Comment: You're assuming a byte has eight bits.

Comment: That means 'unsigned' is not an official description in standard C?

Comment: I tried to clarify your question based on your comments. If I failed to capture your intent, feel free to improve or rollback the edit.

Comment: Compiler will determine the size of the `int`, regardless to system. but you can use `int64_t` or `int32_t`.

Comment: If you mean getting 64-bit for 64-bit CPUs and 32-bit for 32-bit CPUs, `long` is usually used instead. note that int is 32 bit in 64-bit CPUs and for pointer-copying and storing, `long` or (more often) `unsigned long` are used to match CPU word size.

Comment: Can I say the word length of long is always the same as the word length of CPU no matter I am using 32-bit OS or 64-bit OS?

Comment: @JY___ yeah, it's guaranteed by the C standard. Check my comment in Jonathon's reply.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: No, `num_copy` is unsigned, so not negative. Both the shift and the conversion from -1 are well defined (the conversion giving the largest representable value).

Comment: @holgac Whether an architecture is 32-bit or 64-bit is typically determined by the size of pointers. I think even there are exceptions with weird data models. But `intptr_t` should be the better option than `long`. For example the data model on 64-bit Windows has 32-bit longs.

Comment: @typ1232 usually, but not always. word size actually represents CPU register size. There are some architectures using different sized addresses. I think the best way would be bit shifting a register in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@holgac mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519068/how-to-determine-processor-word-length-in-c/29519151?noredirect=1#comment47194315_29519151), the `long` datatype is always the same size as the machine's native word size:

> "A word is the amount of data that a machine can process at one time." "The size of a processor’s general-purpose registers (GPRs) is equal to its word size." "Additionally, the size of the C type long is equal to the word size, whereas the size of the int type is sometimes less than that of the word size"
>
> -- Linux Kernel Development, Ch 17 (3rd edition, pg 381)

As [indicated by Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519068/how-to-determine-processor-word-length-in-c/29519151#comment47194967_29519151) however, this may not apply to machines with small word lengths.

To determine the size of `long` on your compiler, just use `sizeof(long)`:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("long is %d bits on this system\n", (int)sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT);
    return 0;
}
```

See also:

- [What is CHAR_BIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3200954/119527)

Comment: @Angew Agreed, but I interpreted *"system int size"* to mean the size of `int` on your compiler.

Comment: @Anger is right, it's different between compiler's int size and system's

Comment: @JY___ I completely understand that. Your question was ambiguous.

Comment: Can you help me with the correct title of this question?

Comment: `long` is always the same size as CPU word length.

Comment: @holgac is that required by the standard?

Comment: @holgac Citation would be great.

Comment: Linux Kernel Development, Ch 17 (3rd edition, pg 381) says that "A word is the amount of data that a machine can process at one time." "The size of a processor’s general-purpose registers (GPRs) is equal to its word size." "Additionally, the size of the C type long is equal to the word size, whereas the size of the int type is sometimes less than that of the word size"

Comment: @JonathonReinhart also pg 383: "The size of the C long type is guaranteed to be the machine’s word size."

Comment: @holgac Great, thank you. I've incorporated your comments into my answer. If you'd prefer, you can write your own answer, which I would up-vote.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart No need, thank you for the offer :)

Comment: Downvote:  The `long` type is based on a range of values not the processor's word size.  On 8-bit and 16-bit processors, the `long` type would take up more than one processor word in order to meet the range specification. So, by your statement, on an 8-bit processor, the `long` type would have the range of 8 bits, which is smaller than the range of an `int`.

Comment: Sigh, I give up. I'll leave this answer for the discussion in the comments only.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You may be right, the book I've read might be misinforming. Sorry for the confusion, but the book so certainly states that fact that I didn't question it. See this section of the 2nd edition of the same book: http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch19lev1sec2

Comment: Implementations of C on 16-bit processors routinely use 32-bits for long and 16-bits for int.

Answer (score 2):

I think my OCD kicked in a bit here, here is the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define SIZEOF_CHAR sizeof(char)
#define SIZEOF_INT sizeof(int)
#define SIZEOF_LONG sizeof(long)
#define SIZEOF_POINTER sizeof(void *)

#define NIBBLE_BIT 4
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT 8    // should have been defined in <limits.h>
#endif
#define INT_BIT (SIZEOF_INT * CHAR_BIT)
#define LONG_BIT (SIZEOF_LONG * CHAR_BIT)
#define POINTER_BIT (SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT)

int main(void)
{
  char hexchar[SIZEOF_CHAR * 2 + 1],
       hexint[SIZEOF_INT * 2 + 1],
       hexlong[SIZEOF_LONG * 2 + 1],
       hexpointer[SIZEOF_POINTER * 2 + 1];
  int strlen_hexchar, strlen_hexint, strlen_hexlong, strlen_hexpointer;

  strlen_hexchar = sprintf(hexchar, "%x", (unsigned char)-1);
  strlen_hexint = sprintf(hexint, "%x", (unsigned int)-1);
  strlen_hexlong = sprintf(hexlong, "%x", (unsigned long)-1l);
  strlen_hexpointer = sprintf(hexpointer, "%p", (void*)-1l);

  printf("#define SIZEOF_CHAR sizeof(char)                // %2d\n", SIZEOF_CHAR);
  printf("#define SIZEOF_INT sizeof(int)                  // %2d\n", SIZEOF_INT);
  printf("#define SIZEOF_LONG sizeof(long)                  // %2d\n", SIZEOF_LONG);
  printf("#define SIZEOF_POINTER sizeof(void *)           // %2d\n", SIZEOF_POINTER);

  printf("\n");

  printf("#define NIBBLE_BIT %-2d\n", NIBBLE_BIT);
  printf("#ifndef CHAR_BIT\n");
  printf("#define CHAR_BIT %-2d   // should have been defined in <limits.h>\n", CHAR_BIT);
  printf("#endif\n");
  printf("#define INT_BIT (SIZEOF_INT * CHAR_BIT)         // %2d\n", INT_BIT);
  printf("#define INT_LONG (INT_LONG * CHAR_BIT)         // %2d\n", LONG_BIT);
  printf("#define POINTER_BIT (SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT) // %2d\n", POINTER_BIT);

  printf("\n");

  printf("\nTest setup...\n");
  printf("\n");

  printf("char hexchar[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_CHAR + 1],\n");
  printf("    hexint[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_INT + 1],\n");
  printf("    hexlong[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_LONG + 1],\n");
  printf("    hexpointer[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_POINTER + 1];\n");
  printf("int strlen_hexchar, strlen_hexint, strlen_hexlong, strlen_hexpointer;\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("strlen_hexchar = sprintf(hexchar, \"%%x\", (unsigned char)-1);\n//    returned %d, hexchar populated with \"%s\"\n",
      strlen_hexchar, hexchar);
  printf("strlen_hexint = sprintf(hexint, \"%%x\", (unsigned int)-1);\n//    returned %d, hexint populated with \"%s\"\n",
      strlen_hexint, hexint);
  printf("strlen_hexlong = sprintf(hexlong, \"%%x\", (unsigned long)-1);\n//    returned %d, hexlong populated with \"%s\"\n",
      strlen_hexlong, hexlong);
  printf("strlen_hexpointer = sprintf(hexpointer, \"%%x\", (void*)-1l);\n//    returned %d, hexpointer populated with \"%s\"\n",
      strlen_hexpointer, hexpointer);

  printf("\n\nTest results...\n");
  printf("\n");

  if (SIZEOF_CHAR * 2 == strlen_hexchar) {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_CHAR * 2 == strlen_hexchar) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_CHAR * 2 == strlen_hexchar) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", SIZEOF_CHAR * 2, strlen_hexchar);
  }

  if (SIZEOF_INT * 2 == strlen_hexint) {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_INT * 2 == strlen_hexint) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_INT * 2 == strlen_hexint) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", SIZEOF_INT * 2, strlen_hexint);
  }

  if (SIZEOF_LONG * 2 == strlen_hexlong) {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_LONG * 2 == strlen_hexlong) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_LONG * 2 == strlen_hexlong) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", SIZEOF_LONG * 2, strlen_hexlong);
  }

  if (SIZEOF_POINTER * 2 == strlen_hexpointer) {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_POINTER * 2 == strlen_hexpointer) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (SIZEOF_POINTER * 2 == strlen_hexpointer) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", SIZEOF_POINTER * 2, strlen_hexpointer);
  }

  printf("\n");

  if (CHAR_BIT == strlen_hexchar * NIBBLE_BIT) {
    printf("testing (CHAR_BIT == strlen_hexchar * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (CHAR_BIT == strlen_hexchar * NIBBLE_BIT) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", CHAR_BIT, strlen_hexchar * NIBBLE_BIT);
  }

  if (INT_BIT == strlen_hexint * NIBBLE_BIT) {
    printf("testing (INT_BIT == strlen_hexint * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (INT_BIT == strlen_hexint * NIBBLE_BIT) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", INT_BIT, strlen_hexint * NIBBLE_BIT);
  }

  if (LONG_BIT == strlen_hexlong * NIBBLE_BIT) {
    printf("testing (LONG_BIT == strlen_hexlong * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (LONG_BIT == strlen_hexlong * NIBBLE_BIT) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", LONG_BIT, strlen_hexlong * NIBBLE_BIT);
  }

  if (POINTER_BIT == strlen_hexpointer * 4) {
    printf("testing (POINTER_BIT == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing (POINTER_BIT == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != $d)\n", POINTER_BIT, strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT);
  }

  printf("\n");

  if ((int)(SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT) == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) {
    printf("testing ((int)(SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT) == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]\n");
  } else {
    printf("testing ((int)(SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT) == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) [fail]\n");
    printf("  (%d != %d)\n", (int)(SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT), strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT);
  }

  printf("\nConclusion: this machine word is %d bytes and %d bits\n", SIZEOF_POINTER * 8 / CHAR_BIT, strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT);
  if ((int)(SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT) != strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) {
    printf(" * however this conclusion did not pass the (int)(SIZEOF_POINTER * 8 / CHAR_BIT) == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) test\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output from this code shows the following on my machine:

```
$ sizeofword.exe # from mingw32 shell on windows7
#define SIZEOF_CHAR sizeof(char)                //  1
#define SIZEOF_INT sizeof(int)                  //  4
#define SIZEOF_LONG sizeof(long)                  //  4
#define SIZEOF_POINTER sizeof(void *)           //  4

#define NIBBLE_BIT 4
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT 8    // should have been defined in <limits.h>
#endif
#define INT_BIT (SIZEOF_INT * CHAR_BIT)         // 32
#define INT_LONG (INT_LONG * CHAR_BIT)         // 32
#define POINTER_BIT (SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT) // 32


Test setup...

char hexchar[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_CHAR + 1],
    hexint[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_INT + 1],
    hexlong[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_LONG + 1],
    hexpointer[CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_POINTER + 1];
int strlen_hexchar, strlen_hexint, strlen_hexlong, strlen_hexpointer;

strlen_hexchar = sprintf(hexchar, "%x", (unsigned char)-1);
//    returned 2, hexchar populated with "ff"
strlen_hexint = sprintf(hexint, "%x", (unsigned int)-1);
//    returned 8, hexint populated with "ffffffff"
strlen_hexlong = sprintf(hexlong, "%x", (unsigned long)-1);
//    returned 8, hexlong populated with "ffffffff"
strlen_hexpointer = sprintf(hexpointer, "%x", (void*)-1l);
//    returned 8, hexpointer populated with "FFFFFFFF"


Test results...

testing (SIZEOF_CHAR * 2 == strlen_hexchar) [pass]
testing (SIZEOF_INT * 2 == strlen_hexint) [pass]
testing (SIZEOF_LONG * 2 == strlen_hexlong) [pass]
testing (SIZEOF_POINTER * 2 == strlen_hexpointer) [pass]

testing (CHAR_BIT == strlen_hexchar * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]
testing (INT_BIT == strlen_hexint * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]
testing (LONG_BIT == strlen_hexlong * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]
testing (POINTER_BIT == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]

testing ((int)(SIZEOF_POINTER * CHAR_BIT) == strlen_hexpointer * NIBBLE_BIT) [pass]

Conclusion: this machine word is 4 bytes and 32 bits
```

Comment: that was run on a 32 bit windows 7

Comment: I added long and put it in a gist (https://gist.github.com/f03f1071bce240654ec4.git)

Comment: And I guess I should add so it will be on point that the sizeof(void*) * CHAR_BIT should be the machine word size in bits, however it might actually be sizeof(void*) * 8.  Not really sure, but should actually be the same I think.  UTC-8 or 16 or what ever, a char is 8 bits in C.  But then again there will always be acceptations.  One thing you can rely on is that a nibble is always 4 bits.  So using sprintf should validate that.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't `sizeof` allowed?

Also, a slightly improved implementation (no need for a copy, less runs of the loop and no division):

```
int main(){
    int num = 1;
    int count = 0;    

    while(num <<= 8){
        count++;
    }

    printf("System size of int:%d", count+1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right about this. sizeof() also gets the compiler's int size.I was thinking whether there is some way like macro #program to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

As an interview question, the only correct way to do it in straight C is to use conditional compilation. The conditional compilation allows the word size to be defined differently for the various platforms the software runs on, or identified in a way so that the correct size can be obtained from a database. Since a company knows which platforms the product will run on, or which platforms they are willing to support, the platform can be chosen at compile or run-time, and the right word size will be selected as a result.

Any other way of sussing out the word size will either be platform/system specific code or a heuristic. One possible heuristic is to use the size of a pointer to represent the machine word size.

```
word_size = sizeof(void *);
```

Given this is a heuristic, [there are platforms for which it will fail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Word_size_versus_address_size).

Comment: Will this work on architectures where function pointers are more than just a pointer? I recall Itanium being strange in that regard, with a function "descriptor" or the like.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I changed it to a regular pointer. The idea is to choose something that the machine is willing to use an entire register to hold. This is likely to work for 16-bit systems, for which `sizeof(long)` has to fail.

Comment: There are some 64bit architectures using 32bit pointers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Word_size_versus_address_size

Comment: @holgac: Thanks, noted in the answer.