# Trying to understand printf a pointer with a char specifier (%c)

Tags: c, format-specifiers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int n = 2;
   printf("%c",&n);
}
```

Output: L

On using `%d` it of course gives the address of variable `n` but why is it outputting L on using `%c`?

Comment: Because a pointer is not a character, so this code is **undefined behavior**. It could do anything else as well. It's a random effect on your particular environment that the part of a pointer `printf()` will evaluate when trying to get a character translates to H...

Comment: I can smell UB. The only thing happening is UB.

Comment: Hehe, so **now** it's *suddenly* "L"? Do you feel there's something not quite right now?

Comment: "but why is it outputting L on using %c?" --> What did you expect?

Answer (score 8):

It is **undefined behaviour** because you have used **wrong format specifier**.

**C11 Standard: 7.21.6.1 : paragraph 9:**

> If a **conversion specification is invalid**, the behavior is
>   **undefined**. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is **undefined**.

It means anything can happen if `printf` is called with a wrong format specifier.

Answer (score 4):

As the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165769/8051589) of [rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6935629/rsp) said the behaviour is undefined and anything could happen.

In your case the following happens:

It reads one byte of `&n` because a character is of one byte size which is mostly 8 bits long, see [`CHAR_BIT` explanation on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200969/8051589). Then it prints it as character.
This byte could be the first byte of `&n` if the types `int*` and `int` are the same at your machine. That would mean that your variable `n` lies at address `0x48...` (big-endian) or `0x...48` (little-endian) as `0x48` is `H` in the [Ascci code](http://www.asciitable.com/). I assume that your program is using Ascii for encoding which doesn't necessarily have to.
(You changed the character from `H` to `L` but I leave this answer as it is.)
Also this byte can lie somewhere in the middle of the `&n` if an `int*` exceeds the size of an `int` at your system.

You should compile with more warnings enabled for example `-Wall` in gcc and you will get:

> warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

In the case you cast that value to a `char` the behaviour will be well defined but rely on the implementation as a cast of a pointer type to an integer is implementation defined.

Nevertheless what you're doing makes no sense also with a cast it will not do.

Comment: still a few imprecisions (which happens easily reasoning about UB): 1.) ascii isn't mandated 2.) a `char` is **always** a byte, but a byte might have more than 8 bits 3.) with a cast, it's not undefined, but still not particularly useful because the result of the conversion of a pointer to an integer type is *implementation defined* -- still upvoted, explanations are helpful!

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: Answer assumes `int` and `int*` are the same size and  an `int` and `int*` are passed to `printf()` via the same mechanism.  Neither are specified in C.

Comment: @chux: I described what behaviour happened on his machine saying it is undefined. Or did I get something wrong what do you mean?

Comment: This answer does say the behavior is undefined, but then goes on to describe "In your case the following happens.", which IMO, overstates the certitude.  The address could exceed the width of `int` and so the byte extracted is not the first nor the last, but potentially a "middle" one.  An `int` and address may pass in different ways, thus the `L` or `H` are simply garbage - no relation to the address.  Understanding various outcomes of UB is good, yet ascertaining definite behavior about UB to a  leaner is not helpful.

Comment: @chux: Didn't thought about that! Thank you I will add that tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you told printf() function to show the first 1-byte of int n's address as a char.