# How can I define a type that is equal to 16 byte

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I want to define a type that be equal to an array of 16 byte. Something such as this:

```
typedef uint8_t[16] mynewType;
```

but I am getting error. How can I define such type?

I am getting several errors on this line such as:

```
missing ';' before '['  
empty attribute block is not allowed    
missing ']' before 'constant'
'constant'
```

Comment: Could do `using mynewType = struct { char data[16]; };`.  That will avoid the array degenerating into a pointer at a the drop of a hat.

Comment: @Eljay But is does not guarantee the type is exactly 16 bytes wide.  There could be padding or if `CHAR_BIT` is more than 8 then it would also be larger.

Comment: @NathanOliver _"The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes occupied by a non-potentially-overlapping object of the type of its operand"_ and _"sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1"_, regardless of `CHAR_BIT`

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks.  At least now I know `CHAR_BIT` bits is a byte.

Comment: @NathanOliver • one oddball platform I worked on, a byte (or char) was 13-bits.  A word (or int) was 26-bits.

Comment: @Eljay Interesting. Can you please share which platform is this? Is it a widely used platform or a special system?

Comment: The platform is modern C++ (C++11 or later).  Modern C++ is widely used.

Comment: @Eljay I mean the platform that has char size of equal to 13 bits! Which processor supporting it?

Comment: lol, oops, I thought you were referring to the other comment.  The 13-bit platform was created as a virtual machine by a professor at my university.  He would torture students by forcing them to use his 13-bit platform for his assignments, such as creating a compiler/linker or assembler, and the students had to get a ton of badly written documentation from Kinko's ($$$).  I think he created his virtual machine in the 1960s, back when some machines had 6-bit bytes, others had 36-bit bytes; on a PDP-8 (a 12-bit machine).  Wild and wooly times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

```
typedef uint8_t mynewType [16];
```

Answer (score 6):

A typedef is like a declaration, but with an extra `typedef` in front.

So if

```
uint8_t my_array[16];
```

declares a new array.

```
typedef uint8_t my_array[16];
```

makes `my_array` the type of such an array.

Answer (score 2):

Like an array variable:

```
typedef uint8_t mynewType[16];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef unsigned char mynewType [16];
```

is the portable way of allocating 16 bytes on *any* platform; `CHAR_BIT` does not *necessarily* have to be 8.

Comment: Is a byte 8 `CHAR_BIT` or is it just 8 bits? Do you still call a 16 bit char a byte on those types of sytems?

Comment: Indeed I would. The term *octet* is used to describe exactly 8 bits.

Comment: What do you think of this blog post? https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/how-many-bits-has-a-byte/

Comment: @FredLarson: That's the POSIX standard, which is not at the time of writing the same as the C++ standard. POSIX also states that a user defined variable ending with `_t` puts the entire program into an undefined state!

Comment: Except that `uint8_t` *et al* are now part of C++11 and C99, not just POSIX.

Comment: @FredLarson: I'm not sure about that. That's a question in itself. I'll keep an eye out and upvote it should you pose it.

Comment: I might have been incorrect, reading more closely the comments discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200969/10077

Comment: @FredLarson: Would still be a good question: makes a change to all the  `i++ + ++i` trash we get these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a struct with an array field of that size. But you will still need to set the individual byte values. You can also use a union if you want to access the different memory chunks in different ways.

```
// simple data structure of 16 bytes
struct pack_16 {
    uint8_t data[16];
}
// sizeof(pack_16) == 16

// multi type access of 16 bytes
union multi_pack_16 {
    uint8_t  uint_8[16];
    uint16_t uint_16[8];
    uint32_t uint_32[4];
    uint64_t uint_64[2];
}
// sizeof(multi_pack_16) == 16
```

Also, depending on your compiler, the `uint128_t` data type may be defined which is 16 bytes in size.