# Storing a song genres in just one byte

Tags: c++

I am trying to save the genre of a song by using **at most 1 byte** in C++ (it is just for academic purposes, not for production or something like that). The possible genres are **rock, pop, hip-hop, electronic music and jaz** (so 5), but as well as their combinations (for example a song can be pop and rock at the same time).

What came to my mind at first, is to save the genre as a char (as chars are 1 byte). Then we know that a byte is 8 bits, so we can actually turn the bits that we need. For example, if the first bit is activated, we would know that the song is rock, if the second bit is activated, the song would be of pop genre and so on. Is this a good approach, taking into consideration the situation? So a string like this `11100000` would mean that the song is rock, pop and hip-hop (keeping the **order** I wrote in the beginning).

I am not sure that's the best possible solution, though. The problems I've stumbed upon for now:

1. if someone gives us the string "rp" (the first letters of the genres), we would want to set the first and second bits of the char variable.

Something like this:

```
struct Song
{
    char Genre;
}

void readSongGenre(Song& s, const char* genre)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (genre[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (genre[i] == 'r')
        {
            toggleKthBit(s.Genre, 1);
        }
        else if (genre[i] == 'p')
        {
            toggleKthBit(s.Genre, 2);
        }
        else if (genre[i] == 'h')
        {
            toggleKthBit(s.Genre, 3);
        }
        else if (genre[i] == 'e')
        {
            toggleKthBit(s.Genre, 4);
        }
        else if (genre[i] == 'j')
        {
            toggleKthBit(s.Genre, 5);
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Isn't this kind of problematic, though, as on some machines the way of storing data-types is different (little-endian, big-endian).

2. Next thing that I wanted to have as functionaly is to be able to easily convert the bit sequence to a string: so for example `11100000` would be translated to `Rock&Pop&Hip-hop`, which I did in the following way:

   void printGenre(char genre)
   {
   int countOfSetBits = 0;

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
   {
       if (isKthBitSet(genre, i))
       {
           countOfSetBits++;
       }
   }

   int printed = 0;

   if (isKthBitSet(genre, 1))
   {
       printed++;
       if (countOfSetBits != printed)
       {
           std::cout << "Rock&";
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << "Rock";
       }
   }

   if (isKthBitSet(genre, 2))
   {
       printed++;
       if (countOfSetBits != printed)
       {
           std::cout << "Pop&";
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << "Pop";
       }
   }

   if (isKthBitSet(genre, 3))
   {
       printed++;
       if (countOfSetBits != printed)
       {
           std::cout << "Hip-Hop&";
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << "Hip-Hop";
       }
   }

   if (isKthBitSet(genre, 4))
   {
       printed++;
       if (countOfSetBits != printed)
       {
           std::cout << "Electronic&";
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << "Electronic";
       }
   }

   if (isKthBitSet(genre, 5))
   {
       printed++;
       if (countOfSetBits != printed)
       {
           std::cout << "Jaz&";
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << "Jaz";
       }
   }
   ```

   }

I realise that's not really smart. Another functionality I would want my application to have is to be able to find in a collection of songs which of them have a particular combinations (or just one) genre. So for example I would want given the string "pr", to find all songs that are either pop, either rock.

Comment: Weird note: `char` is always 1 byte, but 1 byte need not be 8 bits. [Some of the gory details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200954/what-is-char-bit)

Comment: I would use an enumeration of type `uint8_t` . That'll give you up to 255 named integer constants for genres that only take up 8 bits.

Comment: Added bonus of above is if you get one of those rare cases where a byte isn't 8 bits, you should get a compiler error, *`uint8_t` is not defined* or similar.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks for the response! Can you clarify your idea a little further, as I don't see how I could use it?

Comment: @NathanOliver, when I create a song, how would I modify and then read its genre?

Comment: "Is this a good approach" makes this opinion-based.

Comment: `std::bitset<5>` would also be easy to work with. Note that endianness is about byteorder, so it doesn't matter for a single byte.

Comment: When you are using a single byte endianess is not a factor. That's only for multibyte quantities. What you are describing sounds like a standard solution to me.

Comment: When reading genre, you probably want to set the bit rather than toggle the bit; that way you don't get a string like "hh" toggling the bit on then off.

Comment: @NathanOliver, may you clarify your idea for me, please?

Comment: @user4581301 -- why should having more than 8 bits be an error? If the code assumes 8 bits (and uses `unsigned char`) it will work just fine when `unsigned char` is larger than 8 bits. It's not allowed to be smaller. If you like the fancy-named types, use `uint_least8_t`, which is guaranteed to exist and will have at least 8 bits.

Comment: There's only one question here: Is this a good approach, taking into consideration the situation? The answer is likely "yes". If you only have 8 bits, using 1 bit per genre seems good, if a song can fall into multiple genres at the same time.

Comment: @PeteBecker depends on how the implementation interpreted `uint8_t` being optional. If you want 8 bits and the implementation cannot give 8 bits, that could be cause for leaving `uint8_t` undefined. For this case I agree `uint_least8_t` would be an easy fix if the system could, for example, provide 14 bits. But when you want 8 and cannot get 8, knowing you didn't get 8 is important.

Comment: I support @Artyer. Use `std::bitset<5>` and do it exactly how you anticipate to do it in your head.

Comment: @SAQ Create an enum like `enum Genre : uint8_t { ... }`; and then you have one enum member for each genre that you want to supp[ort.  Then in your song class you would have a member like `Genre genre;` that stores the genre of the song.  A nice thing with this approach is then it allows you to map your enumerations to string either using the enumeration value as in index into an array of strings or as the key of a `std::map<Genre, std::string>`

Comment: @user4581301 -- when you want **exactly** 8 and cannot get 8 you need to know that. There's nothing in the question that indicates that there is a requirement for **exactly** 8 bits, and nothing in the question suggests that such a requirement would be appropriate.

Comment: Storing things in just one byte limits you to 256 options... No way around that.

Comment: If one song has multiple genre, then you might want bitmasks and there is only 8 options..

Comment: Elwood: “What kind of music do you usually have here?” Claire: “Oh, we got both kinds. We got Country and Western!”

Comment: Seriously though, "on some machines the way of storing data-types is different (little-endian, big-endian" *This is not a concern*. Bits in a byte do not have endianness. Bit 0 is 2^0 (two to the power of zero) on all machines. Bit 1 is 2^1 (two to the power of one) on all machines. Bits 3, 5 and 7 together is 2^3 + 2^5 + 2^7 = 168 on all machines.

Comment: The worst feature of your approach is that you reverse the meaning of "n-th bit in a byte". Any other coder treats the Least Significant Bit as having an index 0. In your `11100000` the bits that are set are 5,6,and 7, but you treat them as "1, 2, 3", which makes code completely unreadable and hinders the use of indexes. 

Even in a decimal notation, the first (index 0) digit is the rightmost, denoting ones, the second (index 1) is tens, and you can easily tell the the fourth (index 3) is thousands, and millions are index 6, so it's the seventh digit.  The first digit in a number 12345 is 5.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer what I think is the main question:

> Isn't this kind of problematic, though, as on some machines the way of storing data-types is different (little-endian, big-endian)

You should think how the data would get to the other machine. Are you going to write an object of type `Song` to a file, send this file by email to someone else and use a copy of your application on that person's machine?

Problems could appear if you have all of the following:

1. You read and write your `Song` using [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite)
2. Your type for holding genres has more than 1 byte
3. The endianness of the machines is different

You probably shouldn't use `fwrite` to store your `struct` in a file — this will trigger endianness problems for multi-byte types such as `int`. See [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for ideas on what to do instead.

You probably should not limit yourself to 8 genres, to allow for improved versions of your code. Use a big number like 64 or define a constant and use `std::bitset<N>` to make extending easier.

Also, what about free-text for genres? This way, users could invent genres without you having to update your code to keep up with musical trends. This is non-trivial decision (what happens if someone decides to put profanity into this field?).

Comment: Bottom line: *portability*. Anyways since *it is just for academic purposes, not for production or something like that* then you won’t worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of taste, here's how I would do it with `enum` and free-functions. Changing the `Repr` type allows you to add more genres.

Unfortunately there's no `constexpr` `map` constructor, if it existed, we wouldn't need to use `switch` and the code would be more compact.

```cpp
namespace music
{
    using Repr = unsigned char;
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<Repr>, "Repr is not integral!");

    enum class Genre: Repr
    {
        ROCK = 0b1,
        POP = 0b10,
        HIP_HOP = 0b100,
        ELECTRONIC_MUSIC = 0b1000,
        JAZZ = 0b10000,
        DREAM_THEATER_KIND_STUFF = 0b100000
    };

    using Genres = Repr;

    
    // Mixing operators
    Genres operator|(Genre lhs, Genre rhs)
    {
        return static_cast<Repr>(lhs) | static_cast<Repr>(rhs);
    }
    
    Genres operator|(Genres lhs, Genre rhs)
    {
        return lhs | static_cast<Repr>(rhs);
    }
    
    Genres operator|(Genre lhs, Genres rhs)
    {
        return static_cast<Repr>(lhs) | rhs;
    }

    // todo /bb/ define |= operators

    
    constexpr Genre codeToGenre(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'r':
                return Genre::ROCK;
            case 'p':
                return Genre::POP;
            case 'h':
                return Genre::HIP_HOP;
            case 'e':
                return Genre::ELECTRONIC_MUSIC;
            case 'j':
                return Genre::JAZZ;
            case 'd':
                return Genre::DREAM_THEATER_KIND_STUFF;
            default:
                throw std::runtime_error("Unknown short code: " + std::format("{:c}", c));
        }
    }

    
    // Single genre
    constexpr std::string to_string(Genre g)
    {
        switch (g)
        {
            case Genre::ROCK:
                return "Rock";
            case Genre::POP:
                return "Pop";
            case Genre::HIP_HOP:
                return "Hip Hop";
            case Genre::ELECTRONIC_MUSIC:
                return "Electronic Music";
            case Genre::JAZZ:
                return "Jazz";
            case Genre::DREAM_THEATER_KIND_STUFF:
                return "Dream Theater kind stuff";
            default:
                throw std::runtime_error("Unknown genre: " + std::format("0b{:b}", static_cast<Repr>(g)));
        }
    }

    // Mixed genres
    constexpr std::string to_string(Genres r)
    {
        std::string str;
        
        Repr mask = 0b1;
        auto const reprSize = sizeof(Repr)*8;
        for (auto i=0u; i<reprSize; ++i)
        {
            Repr currentGenre = r & mask;
            if (currentGenre)
            {
                try
                {
                    str += (i > 0 ? ", " : "") + to_string(static_cast<Genre>(currentGenre));
                }
                catch (...) {} // Ignore unkown fields
            }
            mask = mask << 1;
        }
        return str;
    }


    // parse
    Genres parse(std::string str)
    {
        Repr r{0};
        for (auto i=0u; i<str.size(); ++i)
        {
            r = r | codeToGenre(str[i]);
        }
        return r;
    }


    bool match(Genres what, Genres pattern)
    {
        return (what & pattern) == pattern;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << music::to_string(music::Genre::HIP_HOP) << std::endl; // Hip Hop

    std::cout << std::format("0b{:b}", music::Genre::ROCK | music::Genre::HIP_HOP | music::Genre::POP) << std::endl; // 0b111

    std::cout << music::to_string(music::Genre::ROCK | music::Genre::HIP_HOP) << std::endl; // Rock, Hip Hop

    music::Genre g = music::codeToGenre('d');
    std::cout << std::format("0b{:b}", static_cast<music::Repr>(g)) << std::endl; // 0b100000

    music::Genres parsed = music::parse("rpd");
    std::cout << std::format("0b{:b}", parsed) << std::endl; // 0b100011
    std::cout << music::to_string(parsed) << std::endl; // Rock, Pop, Dream Theater kind stuff

    std::cout << music::match(music::parse("rpd"), music::Genre::ROCK | music::Genre::POP) << std::endl; // true (1)
    std::cout << music::match(music::parse("rpd"), music::Genre::ROCK | music::Genre::HIP_HOP) << std::endl; // false (0)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most memory-efficient way to do this would be to set #defines like this:

```cpp
#define ROCK    0b1     //1
#define POP     0b10    //2
#define HIP_HOP 0b100   //4
#define TECHNO  0b1000  //8
#define JAZZ    0b10000 //16
```

Set flags like this (either with math or switch/case depending on input format):

```cpp
Genre |= POP; //Genre is any 8-bit type, doesn't really matter which one
```

Unset like this:

```cpp
Genre &= ~POP; //'~' is bit negation for those who don't know
Genre &= ~((char)POP) //you can explicitly cast POP to an 8-bit type
                      //to make sure all the flags work correctly
```

And read like this:

```cpp
some_val_or_output = Genre & POP;
```

This is the fastest way because bit operations are much faster than math operations, and the most memory efficient because

1. #define means that the compiler will translate every occurrence of the defined word into it's value before compiling,
2. Advanced data types proposed by other answers have additional data in them on top of their values (courtesy of OOP)

Comment: The solution isn't bad, but ditch the macros - it's not the 90's! Use `constexpr uint8_t` instead.

Comment: Yes, that would be safer, or at least more explicit. I used the #defines to show off that you can be very memory-efficient here, but for OP's purpose constexpressions would be better.

Comment: `constexpr` is no less memory efficient.

Comment: #define pollutes instruction memory, while constexpr goes into .rodata. This means that, in assembly, you perform `mov rax, 5` instead of `mov rax, [var]`. This is slightly faster and marginally more memory efficient.

Comment: No, the compiler can (and where it makes sense, generally will) put the data directly into the instructions. Consider [this godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7zWeKj5Gq). Even with optimisations turned off (O1) it still holds the data directly in the assembly instruction, `add eax, 13`